# How do I make my carousel respond to url changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I have a gallery, that opens individual images in a carousel.
Unfortunately, I can't make it respond to URL path changes.

```
const { signatura } = useParams();

const selectedPhotoIndex = useSelector(selectSelectedPhotoIndex);
console.log(selectedPhotoIndex);
const photos = useSelector(selectPhotos);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPhotos = () => {
    dispatch(getPhotos());

    const photoIndex = photos.findIndex((photo, index) => {
      console.log(index, photo.signatura, signatura);

      return photo.signatura === signatura;
    });

    console.log(photoIndex, photos, signatura);
    dispatch(setSelectedPhotoIndex(photoIndex));
  };

  fetchPhotos();
}, [dispatch]);

const selectedPhoto = photos[selectedPhotoIndex];

if (!selectedPhoto) {
  return <div> Photo not found </div>;
}
```

Slice:

```js
  setSelectedPhotoIndex: (state, action) => {
    state.selectedPhotoIndex = action.payload;
  },
  setSelectedPhoto: (state, action) => {
    state.selectedPhoto = action.payload;
  },
}

...
export const selectSelectedPhoto = state => {
  const selectedPhotoIndex = state.gallery.selectedPhotoIndex;
  const photos = state.gallery.photos;

  if (selectedPhotoIndex >= 0 && selectedPhotoIndex < photos.length) {
    return photos[selectedPhotoIndex];
  }

  return null;
};
```

I have tried making my `useEffect` dependent on the `signatura` path parameter from `useParams`:

```js
  ...
  fetchPhotos();
}, [dispatch, signatura]);
```

as well as setting the `selectedPhoto` directly

```js
dispatch(setSelectedPhoto(photo.signatura));
```

None of those seem to work when editing the URL manually.

The reproducible example is [here](https://github.com/ydrea/Rleaf/tree/notfound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can tell you have a single side-effect that is doing too much. It dispatches an action to get all the photos while at the same time it tries to read the current/initial `photos` value selected from state to compute a selected photo index based on the `signatura` route path parameter.

Because of the way Javascript closures work, the `photos` value in the `fetchPhotos` function won't ever be the updated photos that were fetched. In other words, it's an issue of a stale closure.

## Solution

Split the logic of fetching the photos from the logic of computing a derived selected photo index value by using two `useEffect` hooks.

```js
const { signatura } = useParams();

const photos = useSelector(selectPhotos);
const selectedPhotoIndex = useSelector(selectSelectedPhotoIndex);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPhotos());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
  const photoIndex = photos.findIndex(
    (photo) => photo.signatura === signatura
  );

  dispatch(setSelectedPhotoIndex(photoIndex));
}, [dispatch, photos, signatura]);

const selectedPhoto = photos[selectedPhotoIndex];
```

In my opinion you don't need the `selectedPhotoIndex` state at all. Recall that above I called this a derived value, e.g. a value *derived* from the current `photos` state ***and*** the current `signatura` route path parameter. It's a general React anti-pattern to store derived "state" in state.

Here's a suggested example skipping the stored `selectedPhotoIndex` state:

```js
const { signatura } = useParams();

const photos = useSelector(selectPhotos);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPhotos());
}, [dispatch]);

const selectedPhoto = photos.find(
  (photo) => photo.signatura === signatura
);
```

You could, if you wanted to, memoize the selected photo value using the `useMemo` hook:

```js
const selectedPhoto = React.useMemo(() => photos.find(
  (photo) => photo.signatura === signatura
), [photos, signatura]);
```

In fact, it's a bit of a "rule of thumb" that when you catch yourself creating a `useState/useEffect` or `useSelector/useEffect` "coupling" that you are implementing the anti-pattern and should just compute and use the derived value directly in the component.